Configure Filebeat Nginx module with Beats CRD
The Problem
Hello, I'm trying to set up the nginx module of Filbeats to parse the logs of an nginx pod in my Kubernetes cluster.
Context
I'm using the Beats CRD with the following configuration:
apiVersion: beat.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Beat
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: elastic-system
spec:
  type: filebeat
  version: 8.12.0
  secureSettings:
    - secretName: beats-secret
  config:
    filebeat:
      autodiscover:
        providers:
          - type: kubernetes
            node: ${NODE_NAME}
            add_resource_metadata:
              deployment: true
              cronjob: true
            hints:
              enabled: true
              default_config:
                type: container
                paths:
                  - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log

And on my specific nginx pods, I have added the following annotation:
      annotations:
        co.elastic.logs/module: nginx
        co.elastic.logs/module.nginx.access.enabled: "true"
        co.elastic.logs/module.nginx.access.var.paths: "/var/log/nginx/access.log"
        co.elastic.logs/module.nginx.error.enabled: "true"
        co.elastic.logs/module.nginx.error.var.paths: "/var/log/nginx/error.log"

Based on what I understand from the documentation, this should enable the nginx module only on this pod. But actually, nothing happened. I only got the raw and unparsed message filed.
Could anyone help me?
